# React project using parcel bundler instead of Webpack

Tags: reactjs, parceljs

We can start with React project using command **create-react-app**. But when we use this command we don't get idea about how it's bundle and pack all types of files using Webpack.

So I tried to build react app without **create-react-app** command using Webpack 4 and Babel 7 and I succeed.

Now I want to do same app using parcel bundler. as I read on different blogs I got an idea that parcel is easy then web pack and it's truly zero configuration set up.

My project structure is

```
- src
|- components
|- styles
|- index.html
|- index.js
- package.json
```

This is simple project to start with parcel bundle so I've not add Redux or routing yet.

What I want to achieve is

1). As aspected React app should be run in browser using parcel bundler.

2). I want to use absolute paths when importing JS files.

3). I want to enable hot reloading.

Answer (score 0):

After few minutes of research on net I find the solution and it's truly zero configuration with parcel bundler.

we just need to add 2 commands in package.json file 's script section.

project structure is

```
- src
|- components
|- styles
|- index.html
|- index.js
|- App.js
- package.json
- .babelrc // this file will use to setup absolute path when import files
```

> index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from './App';
import "./style/index.scss";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

> index.html is same file as create-react-app provide we just need div with id.
>
> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Count from "@components/Count"; // here I used absolute path. check .bablerc file
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
         <>
          <div>this is App component</div>
          <Count />
        </>
      );
 }
}
```

> components/Count.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   count: 0
   };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
       count is: {this.state.count}
      <br />
       <button onClick={(prevState) => {this.setState({
         count: prevState.count + 1
        });
      }}
    >
      Add count
      </button>
  </>
);
}
}
```

> style/index.scss

```
body {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

**note that we don't need to manually install node-sass package to use
 scss. parcel will handle for you.**

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "react_parcel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "parcel ./src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.html/"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {   
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

> .bablerc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
     {
       "root": ["./src"],
       "alias": {
         "@components": "./src/components"
       }
     }
    ],
   ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
   ]
}
```

here we add alias for components folder so when we need to import any file from components folder we don't need to write relative path.

**npm run dev**

your server will start on localhost:1234

I solved 2 issues but still need to figure out how to use hot reloading so if you guys have any idea related hot reloading please answer it.

for production build: **npm run build**